# creating custom variables with names for another variable?

Tags: javascript

so i was trying to make custom variables generator but i couldn't figure out the way to create custom variavle with name from string
it keeps sending error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['

can someone help
my code look like this:

```
var tempi = "csv"
var window[tempi]={0:"r"};
```

and i expect it to do

```
var csv ={0:"r"}
```

and create with this multiple variables with diffrent names

Comment: It's not clear to me what the intent here is.  Are you expecting after this code executes that there would be a locally-scoped variable called `windowcsv`?  Something else?

Comment: i expect it to do : var csv ={0:"r"}

Answer (score 0):

Your code looking good. It seems that you dont define window['csv'] previously. Take a look on this example:

```js
tempi = 'csv'
data = [];
data['csv'] = {0: 'hello'};

console.log(data[tempi])
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are using the `var` initializer word for `window`, but `window` is already defined when program loads, so just avoid it:

```js
var tempi = "csv"

window[tempi] = {
    0: "r"
};

console.log(csv)
```